# Manejo de Errores en Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en el cual agrego una consulta a una variable ( por tema de tablas dinámicas ). El problema es que al ingresar una fecha y la tabla no existe el PRC se cae. Es por ello que necesito manejar errores y no lo logro hacer y quería ver si ustedes me pueden ayudar.

Dejo el código para que entiendan mejor la idea.

Como dije anteriormente al ingresar un año y un mes y la tabla no existe, el prc se cae

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[PRC_Reajuste] 

    @cAnio   Varchar(4)   
   ,@cMes    Varchar(2)
   ,@Rut     Varchar(12)

AS
BEGIN

 Declare @Fecha   Varchar(10)  Set @Fecha    = Ltrim((@cAnio)) + Ltrim((@cMes))  

  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tmp_1') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
  DROP TABLE dbo.Tmp_1
  IF (@@error <> 0)
  BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRAN
  RETURN
  END  END

 Declare @Consulta  varchar(800) Set @Consulta = 'Select * into Tmp_1  From [192.168.37.27].coop.dbo.GACPRO_ReajusteCapital_' + @Fecha + ' Where cRut= ' + ''''  + @Rut  + ''''  




 End
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear bloques `TRY-CATCH` muy similares a los que se utilizan en .NET para manejar excepciones.

```
BEGIN TRY
  //Código...
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  //Código...
END CATCH
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.. lo hice de esa forma y funciono.

Comment: Excelente! Cierra la respuesta para posteriores dudas sobre lo mismo amigo... éxito en tú código!

Comment: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)